# Ubuntu install window shows up after restart from installing

Tags: system-installation

I installed Ubuntu five times to try different install options, but ubuntu install window pops up after restart. Any ideas?

Comment: How did you install Ubuntu? Is it alongside Windows? What do you mean by 'Ubuntu Install window'. Didn't you install it properly?

Answer (score 0):

Changing the boot order of the "bootable" devices on your computer, like your hard drive or bootable media in a USB port (e.g. flash drive), floppy drive, or optical drive, is very easy.

The BIOS setup utility is where you change boot order settings.

and remove your ubuntu cd